# What is the correct way of updating state for which the value needed to be a combination of previous state and event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, dom-events

I'm trying to update the state by previous state value and `e.target.value`.

I tried doing it this way because the official document recommends using a function for updating the state when we want to use the previous state but I got an error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

```
state = {
        expression : '',
        result : 0
}
handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState(state => ({ expression: state.expression + e.target.value}))
}
```

But when I tried doing it this way, It was updating the state successfully

```
state = {
        expression : '',
        result : 0
}
handleClick = (e) => {
    let a = e.target.value;
    this.setState(state => ({ expression: state.expression + a}))
}
```

I know the problem is not with the setState, but with the event handling
The other way of doing the same is below but is not recommended by react's official documentation for using previous states

```
state = {
        expression : '',
        result : 0
}
handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({ expression: this.state.expression + e.target.value})
}
```

What what is the correct way of doing this, when we want the previous state value and event value.

My components

```
<h4>{this.state.expression}</h4>

<Button value='2' onClick={this.handleClick}  variant='outline-primary' block>2</Button>
```

Comment: handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({ expression: ... this.state.expression , e.target.value})
} 


Please try this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out, saving the value to a variable and then using it is the correct way.

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    const {value} = e.target
    this.setState(state => ({ expression: state.expression + value}))
}
```

The reason for needing to saving it to a var is that when you use setState with a function, the function executes *after* the event is over.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your state in this way:

```
state = {
        expression : '',
        result : 0
}
handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ expression: ...this.state.expression, e.target.value})
}
```

As you see I’ve added `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the page of taking any action (such as reload).

Answer (score 1):

Add e.persist(); in your handleClick function i.e

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    e.persist()
    this.setState({ expression: e.target.value })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is asynchronous in nature so the update is not guaranteed to happen immediately.

The difference between

```
this.setState(state => ({ expression: state.expression + e.target.value}))
```

and

```
this.setState({ expression: this.state.expression + e.target.value})
```

*is that the callback function provided to the former `setState` will execute asynchronously i.e. it will be called after the event is over*. Apart from the fact that the latter can have stale values of `this.state.expression` which is why it's not recommended here.

The actual update of `state` in the latter will also be done after the event is over (as `setState` is asynchronous) **but** since you passed an object so the value `e.target.value` is computed right-away.

Correct way is the former but use a variable just as you've done.